# Do I need close db connection in command [django]

Tags: django, django-commands

According to this (http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/926/) snippet, connection closed in handle. But it is kind of old code.

In django 1.4, Do we must close connection? I looked through django code but I cann't find code that closes connection.

If django closes connection where is it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the snippet stated:

```
# Close the DB connection. This is required as a workaround for an
# edge case in MySQL: if the same connection is used to
# create tables, load data, and query, the query can return
# incorrect results.
```

From Django:

```
So, yes, if you do something to deliberately create lots of connections, 
lot of connections will be created. However, Django closes its connection to the 
database at the end of each request/response cycle, so there is only one connection 
in operation per thread or process handling requests and responses. If you're not 
using the HTTP layer, it's still only one connection per thread of execution and 
you are in complete control of the number of threads you create.
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9878

Comment: But the problem is does Django command close connection at the end of the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

First a disclaimer: I'm not an expert (far from it).

Anyway, the snippet you reference refers to to two tickets: the [Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7572) ticket suggests closing the connection has been included in the code for loading fixtures (see lines 55-60 in *django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py*). The [MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37735) ticket suggests nothing on their side has changed much.

Anyway, I think it depends on what you are trying to do. And most importantly, the "connection closing" fix seems a MySQL only thing. If you use any other DB, the bug suggested by the comments in the snippet should not occur.